# Proper word for "Before including Current" value

Tags: phrase-requests

In a web application user interface, I need to tell my users that all past dates are valid from the given date and also including the given date.

For Example:

> Validity: Before 10-08-2012 including 10-08-2012

I'm looking for proper word to use, instead of using before, including and two-time current date at the same line.

There should be a single and more suitable word for this.

What I'm currently using, I want to improve the sentence underline with red color:

[image]

Comment: @Saqib, are you sure that both dates should be same in one line?

Comment: How about: 10-08-2012 and earlier

Comment: @IqbalAhmedSiyal Yes I'm sure both dates must be same. I'm just avoiding mentioning two dates in one line.

Comment: @JamesRandom I think `earlier` sounds perfect here.

Comment: Now I have seen your image, "Up to and including ..." might be better.

Comment: Thanks for other suggestion, I would like to go with "earlier". I have set it like this `Valid Issue Dates:  October 14, 2016 and earlier`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're going to find a single word, but you can shorten the phrase.

Note that it should be *dates* (plural) because more than one is acceptable.

> Valid Issue Dates: 10-4-2018 and earlier.

(I only just now noticed the comments that mirror this.)

---

The only other way of expressing it is if you do something like this:

> Issue Cutoff Date: 10-4-2018

Most people would understand that a cutoff date is a time after which something is no longer accepted. It's like a deadline.

However, it may not be as immediately understood by everyone as the earlier version.

Comment: as James suggested before `earlier` perfectly fits in my case and I have applied this word now.  And because the app mostly targets non-English people and regions, I would ignore `Cutoff` word here. As you said, this will confuse the audience.